# how do I set up a table view in interface builder for a 'settings' type interface

Tags: ios, interface-builder

So I guess the table view has been designed around the idea of using dynamic data received at run time, but I want to make a settings type app where all of the cell values are known as I build it, so I was hoping to be able to set the section / row configuration, labels ect, as well as the properties for each cell (whether it has other views inside it like a switch, or whether it is a button etc) all in interface builder.

can I do that? how?

I am using xcode 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

To use static cell content you have to make sure that you are adding a `UITableViewController` not just a `UITableView` dragged into a `UIViewController`. The latter requires dynamic prototypes.

Once you've added the table view controller to your storyboard it is as simple as selecting "static cells" in the attributes inspector. From there you can drag and drop `UITableViewCells` and modify them as you wish.

Comment: cool, is it possible to do this when not using storyboards? storyboards are only supported in os5 and above right?

Comment: @matt Sorry, I believe static cells were introduced with storyboards.